# Issue with converting a date using Carbon

Tags: sql-server, laravel, datetime2

```
$value="Mar 10 2016 09:12:03:000AM";
return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u0', $value);
```

Please will someone please tell me how to use Carbon to
convert this date to that format.

I'm getting:
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:
Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
The separation symbol could not be found
Unexpected data found.
The format separator does not match
Trailing data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use carbon like

```
$value="Mar 10 2016 09:12:03:000AM";
return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u0');
```

Answer (score 0):

For detail about how to carbon module used please visit on link [Carbon Docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

In controller declare `use Carbon\Carbon;`

```
$value="Mar 10 2016 09:12:03:000AM";
return Carbon::parse($value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$value="Mar 10 2016 09:12:03:000AM";
Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u0');
```

Use parse method to instantiate the $value string as carbon object and then you can use any of the helper functions available in Carbon Library.
Refer to the given link :: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting.